# Lock files to prevent deletion by anything other than my program

Tags: vb.net, file-io, filestream

I want to lock down some files in a folder to prevent other users from deleting/editing them. Then if my program wants to move or delete the file, it temporarily unlocks it, moves/deletes, then relocks it (if moved) to prevent deletion again.

I've read a bit about the filestream read-only property that would stop this - Can I set this property without actually setting up a stream between the program and my file? Are there any other better ways in VB.NET? It needs to prevent file deletions/moves/edits by non administrators unless done so through the program.

Ultimate goal is to bit by bit lock a number of files and folders and only allow my program to move/delete files, this would ensure that only "approved" moves are allowed (I would use `filesystemwatch` to monitor "unapproved moves" by comparing a database of these with a database of "approved" moves).

Comment: If you have an elevated program, you could "claim" the files or folders.

Comment: Passing FileShare.None ensures that nobody else can mess with the file.  Of course your user will simply kill your app with Task Manager if you intend to make his life miserable.

Comment: Can't you just do it with windows permission?

Comment: These files often go missing and we have no idea what is causing them to do so. Unfortunately we have to force people to use a programme to move files as management see it as the only way to keep a proper audit trail of everything that happens

Comment: Also we aren't sure that Windows permission will be enough as it may be circumventing it. Ideally we want to trick the network into thinking these files are being used.

Comment: ("it" being whatever mysterious person or program that is deleting the files)

Comment: Sounds like you need to have less people with Admin rights logged onto your network...

Comment: Unfortunately we are stuck with this situation until our IT department comes kicking and screaming out of the 1980's and cleans up their act. This is just a "best we can do" solution for the time being. The current system in place would be enough to make a grown programmer cry.